# \setuppagenumbering[location=] causes problem in Context

Tags: context, pandoc

I am new to tex world.

I am converting a markdown to pdf, first using the pandoc to create the text and then `ConText` to generate the pdf. I hope to release the template to wider pandoc audience if I can resolve some of the issues.

When I add `\setuppagenumbering[location=]` to the template to remove the default page number in the header, I get the following error. 
Also attached is the tex file for your reference.

```
mtx-context     | run 1: luatex --fmt="C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0
dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en" --interaction="nonstopmode" --jobname="taf-user-guide10" --lua="C:/Programs/con
text/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui" --no-pars
e-first-line --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./taf-user-guide10.tex" --c:input="./taf-user-guide10.tex" --c:kindofrun=
1 --c:maxnofruns=8 --c:nonstopmode "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (rev 5041)
 \write18 enabled.
open source     > 1 > 1 > C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-yes.mkiv

ConTeXt  ver: 2014.09.06 20:59 MKIV beta  fmt: 2014.9.8  int: english/english

system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > 2 > 2 > C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
close source    > 2 > 2 > C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv

system          > files > jobname 'taf-user-guide10', input './taf-user-guide10', result 'taf-user-guide10'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > 2 > 3 > C:/Project/meccano/trunk/docs/user manual/taf-user-guide10.tex
open source     > 3 > 4 > C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv
close source    > 3 > 4 > C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv
fonts           > bodyfont '20pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '24pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '16pt' is defined (can better be done global)
backend         > xmp > using file 'C:/Programs/context/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/lpdf-pdx.xml'
pages           > flushing realpage 1, userpage 1
pages           > flushing realpage 2, userpage 2
structure       > sectioning > title @ level 2 : 0.0 -> \headtext {content}
pages           > flushing realpage 3, userpage 3

lua error       > error on line 150 in file C:/Project/meccano/trunk/docs/user manual/taf-user-guide10.tex:

.../context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/strc-doc.lua:904: attempt to index field 'numbers' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .../context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/strc-doc.lua:904: in function 'getsectionnumber'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk

140       {\tfd {\switchtobodyfont [20pt] TAF User Guide}}
141       \blank[5*big]
142       {\tfa abc}
143       \blank[2*big]
144       {\tfa \currentdate}
145       \blank[3*medium]
146     \stopalignment
147
148     \completecontent
149
150 >>  \chapter{Creating device driver}
151     \section[how-to-create-the]{How to create the}
152
153     asdasdasd adasd a
154
155     \stoptext
```

The Tex File produced by pandoc and converted to pdf using `Context`

```
\startmode[*mkii]
  \enableregime[utf-8]
  \setupcolors[state=start]
\stopmode

% COLOR==================================================
\definecolor [darktheme]             [r=0.43, g=0.00, b=0.00]\definecolor [blockquotebackground]  [r=0.85, g=0.65, b=0.55]\definecolor [codebackground]        [r=0.95, g=0.95, b=1.00]% Enable hyperlinks======================================
\setupinteraction[state=start, color=darktheme]

% PAGE SETUP ================================================
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1in, cutspace=1in, height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]


% HEADER ================================================
%\setupheadertexts[][][][]
\setupfootertexts[\setups{text right}][][][\setups{text left}]
\setuppagenumbering[location=,alternative=doublesided]

\startsetups[text right]
  \rlap{}
  \hfill
  \bf {\sl {TAF User Guide} (420) }
  \hfill
  \llap{\pagenumber}
\stopsetups

\startsetups[text left]
  \rlap{\pagenumber}
  \hfill
  \bf \cap{ Chapter \namedheadnumber{chapter} }  \getmarking[chapter]
  \hfill
  \llap{}
\stopsetups


% BODY ======================================================
\setupbodyfont[palatino,11pt]
\setupwhitespace[medium]


% HEADINGS ==================================================
\unexpanded\def\HeadTitle#1#2%
{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[offset=.5em,frame=off]
\tbox{\framed[width=2cm,align=left]{#1}}%
\tbox{\framed[width=7cm,align=right,leftframe=on]{#2}}%
\egroup}

\setupheads[alternative=inmargin,separator=--,color=darktheme]
\setuphead[chapter]      [style=\tfd \bf, command=\HeadTitle, textstyle=bold]
\setuphead[section]      [style=\tfb \bf]
\setuphead[subsection]   [style=\tf \bolditalic]
\setuphead[subsubsection][style=\bf, number=no]



% BLOCKQUOTE ================================================
\definebackground
  [blockquote]
  [
    framecolor=darktheme,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=blockquotebackground,
    frame=off, 
    leftframe=on,
    rulethickness=2mm,
    offset=overlay,
    leftoffset=2em,
    rightoffset=1em,
    width=\textwidth,
    setups=framedsetups,
    before=\blank,
    after=\blank,
  ]

% CODE ================================================
\definetextbackground
  [verbatim]
  [
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=codebackground,
    backgroundoffset=0mm,
    offset=0.8cm,
    frame=off,
    location=paragraph,
    before=\blank,
    after=\blank,
  ]

\setuptyping
  [typing]
  [margin=2mm,bodyfont=10.0pt,
before={\starttextbackground[verbatim]},
after={\stoptextbackground}]


\definedescription
  [description]
  [headstyle=bold, style=normal, location=hanging, width=broad, margin=1cm]

\setupitemize[autointro]    % prevent orphan list intro
\setupitemize[indentnext=no]

\setupfloats[figure][location=left,width=6.3in]
\setupfloats[table][default={here}]
\setupcaptions[figure][style=bold]

\setupthinrules[width=15em] % width of horizontal rules

\setupdelimitedtext
  [blockquote]
  [before={\blank[medium]},
   after={\blank[medium]},
   indentnext=no,
  ]

% TOC======================================================
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section,subsection}]

% level=4, \subsubsubsections are not listed in ToC
% alternative=c, space to the page number is filled with dots
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={chapter,section}, alternative=c,]

\setuplist[chapter][width=10mm, style=bold]
\setuplist[section][width=20mm, style=normal, pagestyle=normal]
%\setuplist[subsection][width=20mm, style=slanted, pagestyle=normal]

% pagestyle=normal for changing the appearance of pagenumber
%\setuplist[subsubsection][width=20mm, style=slanted, pagestyle=normal]




\starttext

\startalignment[center]
  \blank[4*big]
  {\tfd {\switchtobodyfont [20pt] TAF User Guide}}
  \blank[5*big]
  {\tfa abc}
  \blank[2*big]
  {\tfa \currentdate}
  \blank[3*medium]
\stopalignment

\completecontent

\chapter{Creating device driver}
\section[how-to-create-the]{How to create the}

asdasdasd adasd a

\stoptext
```

Here is a minimal example that shows that same error message.

```
\setupfootertexts[\namedheadnumber{chapter}]
\setuppagenumbering[location=,alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

\completecontent

\chapter{Creating device driver}

\section{How to create the}

Chapter text

\stoptext
```

Comment: That is a nice template! I don't have time to debug this completely right now, but the error occurs due to `\namedheadnumber{chapter}` If you remove that, the error goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Wolfgang Schuster on the context mailing list.

The error only happens when there is no `.tuc` file. The simplest workaround is to use

```
\getmarking[chapternumber]
```

instead of

```
\namedheadnumber{chapter}
```